# My TestNG.xml leads to execution of @BeforeTest method even if there are no tests eligible for execution in that class

Tags: testng

My TestNG.xml comprises of set of this kind of tag:-

```
<test name="Order">
    <groups>
    <run>
            <include name="Smoke" />
            <exclude name="Regression"></exclude>
        </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
        <class name="com.test.myproject.class1"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```

What is happening is Some of the classes only have Regression group names and no Smoke name. So, I was expecting that nothing of those classes should be executed. But, I can see the BeforeTest and AfterTest of these classes getting executed even though none of the tests are eligible to be executed.

Any tip on how can I not allow BeforeTest and AfterTest from getting executed?
I am using TestNG 6.9.9

Here is how my java testng code looks:-

```
@Listeners(AUTEventListener.class)
public class MyTest extends BaseTestCase {

    @Parameters({ "browserName", "gridHubUrl", "gridNodeUrl" })

    @BeforeTest(alwaysRun = true)
    public void testInit(String browserName, String gridHubUrl, String gridNodeUrl) throws Exception {
        //Before Test logic is here
    }


    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void openBrowser() {
        //BeforeMethod logic is here
    }


    @Test(priority = 1, groups={"Regression"}, description = "Testcase to Verify that a claimant is able to file a non cargo claim")
    @TestInfo(testcaseIds={"TC-12344"})
       public void TC_12344_MyTestMethod() throws Exception
       {
        // Test is here
       }
```

Comment: Are you running your tests in parallel? I assume, no. Are your group annotations on @ Test level or on @ Class level? Some code could also be useful. Just a sample to answer the above.

Comment: Hi, I am not running tests in parallel. I have updated my Question above to include the Java code as well. Hope it helps. Waiting to get a solution to this

Answer (score 0):

> Update after OP posted code:

Okay I can see the issue here. Please remove the 'alwaysRun = true'  from your @BeforeTest and @BeforeMethod. It overrides your group execution order!

There is no much purpose using that there as you will still get the desired behaviour (i.e. before anything @BeforeTest will be executed regardsless of your alwaysRun option, followed by @BeforeMethod and there is another tag called @BeforeClass if you want to use it, which precedes @BeforeTest).

If on the long run you desire even more control on how your groups are being executed look at [GroupDependencies](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#test-groups) as well (i.e. don't execute "Regression" if "Smoked" failed)

Best of luck!

Comment: I cant remove the alwaysrun=true because I want my AfterMethod to execute even if the test fails.

Comment: Then you will need to use (dependsOnMethods) along with priorities to get the desired effect

Answer (score 0):

`groups` is available on `@BeforeX`/`@AfterX` too.

Add the appropriate value, and it should work as expected.